# Why class instance as pointer uses heap and not stack?

Tags: c++

I read in a c++ book that we can have to kinds of class instances in c++.

1. Normal class instances
2. Class instances as pointer

For example :

```
class Person {
public:
    Person();
    Person(std::string name, int age){

    }
};

    //This will be created in the stack
    A :  Person John("John",68);
    //This will be created in the heap
    B :  Person *Marcel("Marcel",31);
```

So, why when we are creating an object using pointer (A) uses **Heap** and why in B, it will uses **Stack**?

Comment: B is not valid syntax.

Comment: You have it backwards: When you create an object dynamically, you get back a pointer to it.  How else would you know where the object is?  You can also make a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration using the address-of operator (`&`).

Comment: I question a book that categorizes class instances as "pointer" and "normal".  You may benefit from finding a better book.

Comment: You should add compilable code to the question. Now it doesn't make any sense, really.

Comment: Suggest a title for my question. I couldn't write it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's correct the syntax:

```
int main()
{
Person John("John",68);  //statement 1
Person *Marcel = new Person("Marcel",31); //statement 2
....
}
```

- The first statement, indeed, creates a instance of the class Person,
  on the stack.
- The second statement declares a pointer of type `Person` on the stack, and assigns it an instance of the class `Person` which is on the heap, because it is dynamically allocated. So, the pointer (i.e. the variable the holds the address of the class instance) resides on the stack, but the actual instance is allocated on the heap.

I hope this clears things up, if not, I recommend going back to basics and looking up pointers.